# Creating and accessing a new page from blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to create a new blade.php page, I need to access this page by pressing a button on my home page, but it isn't working properly.

How can I do it?

I tried doing
`Route::get('/my-page', function () { return view('my-page'); });`
inside web.php, it works, but when I  press the card button, it doesn't work
`

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 my-1">
<a href="{{ route('course-page') }}">
<div class="card card-animated text-center py-5">
<span class="">
<img class="img-fluid" src="assets/image/courses.svg" >
</span>
<div class="card-body">
<p class="card-text">COURSES</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Add a `name` to your route if you want to access it via `route('course-page')` https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a route by *route name* while you did not define the route name. Add a name for your route:

```php
Route::get('/my-page', function () { return view('my-page'); })->name('course-page');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Change in web.php

```
Route::get('/my-page', function () { return view('my-page'); })->name('course-page');
```

Welcome in advance.